# Read from files and parse SQL table

Tags: c#, sql-server, odbc

All the following must be done in C#. Parsing the SQL table (SQL Server) will be done using methods in `System.Data.Odbc`.

Let's assume I have two .csv files, `fi1` and `fi2`. The first csv file has two columns `id` and `val1`, and the second csv has two columns as well, `id` and `val2`.

I would like to read the two files, and parse the output to one SQL table with the following columns: `id, val1, val2`.

The problem is that the two files may have different entries in the `id` columns: in other words, some id's may have a `val1` value but no `val2` value, and vice versa, or they might have both values.

The table should contain the union of the `id` columns in the two files.

Example:

**File 1**

[image]

**File2**

[image]

The way I would want the final SQL table to look like is this:

[image]

Note that each file might contain duplicates, and we would want to exclude the duplicates when parsing the SQL table.

The thought I had is to create two dictionaries, `dict1` and `dict2`, where the key would be the `id`, and the value would be `val1` and `val2`. Dictionaries will be used to make sure that duplicates are not included:

```
 Dictionary<string, string> dict1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 string[] header1 = new string[]{};

 using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fi1))
 {
     header1 = rdr.ReadLine().Split(',');
     while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
     {
          string ln = rdr.ReadLine();
          string[] split_ln = ln.Split(',');
          dict1.Add(split_ln[0], split_ln[1]);
     }
 }

 Dictionary<string, string> dict2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 string[] header2 = new string[]{};

 using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fi2))
 {
     header2 = rdr.ReadLine().Split(',');
     while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
     {
          string ln = rdr.ReadLine();
          string[] split_ln = ln.Split(',');
          dict2.Add(split_ln[0], split_ln[1]);
     }
 }
```

However, after adding each file to a dictionary, I am not sure how to match the id's of both dictionaries.

Would anyone have a good hint as to how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Why is anyone voting to close this post? It has both a reproducible example and shows what I have tried. I am not sure what's the problem here.

Comment: Not really, I have never used a Tuple. Could you please tell me how you suggest using it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if your data is clean?  Do all keys in File1 have a match in File2  Is there a 1-1, 1-many, or many-many relationship between the files?  And what should be done in the case where there is not a match?

Comment: The keys don't have to have a match. All I want is to take the union of the keys, and if a key doesn't have a corresponding value in one of the values, just assign null or something.

Comment: In the case where there is not a match, do you need to distinguish that the key comes from file1 or file2?

Comment: No it doesn't matter really..

Comment: why dont you just use sql `Join`

Comment: Why is it necessary to go through C#?  I would import both CSV's into SQL Server and then use TSQL to join them.

Comment: Unfortunately, our production process is in C#, and thisstep is a part and parcel of production.

Comment: How are you planning to use the resulting set?  Is it meant to be a business object used in code?  Is it meant to populate a new table somewhere in SQL Server?  There may be different solutions that vary based on your end goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do atually do a list of tuples to hold the values here instead of a dictionary so that all the information is in one place rather than matching keys, each tuple corresponds to a table record

```
var dict = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fi1))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string ln = rdr.ReadLine();
                string[] split_ln = ln.Split(',');
                dict.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(split_ln[0], split_ln[1],null));
            }
        }
        using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fi2))
        {
            while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string ln = rdr.ReadLine();
                string[] split_ln = ln.Split(',');
                if (dict.Any(item => item.Item1 == split_ln[0]))
                {
                    var item = dict.Find(i => i.Item1 == split_ln[0]);
                    var newtuple = new Tuple<string, string, string>(item.Item1, item.Item2, split_ln[1]);
                    dict.Remove(item);
                    dict.Add(newtuple);
                }
                else
                {
                    dict.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>(split_ln[0],null,split_ln[1]));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This sounds very simple and great! However, would it be possible to add an item to the tuple that only has val1 (in file1) and no value val2 in file2?

Comment: it actually does this, all the values in file one are added to the list, then when file two is being read it will check the items added from file 1, and update them if necessary, but will leave the ones that have no file 2 equivalent alone